# Difference Between Take Off and Starting Collar - Which One Should I Use?

Tags: hvac, humidifier

I am in the process of installing a whole house humidifier. I am planning to mount it to the supply side and need to connect the bypass to the return. I'm not sure if I should be using a take-off or starting collar to do this. I've posted pictures below. I apologize if my terminology is incorrect. With the starting collar, do you use screws to secure it to the plenum, or do you simply fold all of the tabs back? One thing that I like about the take-off is that there is an adhesive strip and holes for 3 zip screws. I apologize for the questions. I am learning HVAC for the first time, and I don't have much experience yet.

[image: Starting Collar]

[image: Take-Off]

Comment: The problem with adhesive strips is they do fail but then you have the screws , I usually make my own and make the hole tight. Fold the fingers and you have a good mechanical connection, I will usually use a bead of silicone to reduce any leaks.

Comment: Tabs and screws from what I’ve seen. When in doubt use both (except for dryer vents where screws can be a fire hazard).

Answer (score 1):

Start collars and take offs are terminology that are used interchangeably.  Finger type ( fold over tabs) are generally used in duct board plenum and trunk lines.  Collar types are used with sheet metal distribution systems.  Sheet metal uses three short metal screws in each collar with mastic or other sealing products.  The finger type collar has flexible duct attached with a first layer duct tape, attaching the inner liner to the collar.  Next is a coating of mastic over the tape completely.  Pull the flexible insulation and vapor barrier over the joint and secure with a large nylon zip tie.  Trim the zip tie and you are done.